# Why is VisualStudio not returning my json

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

Some javascript code calls a URL and uses a promise function for the result. This is the specific ionic factory code (from a tutorial at [this blog by Andrew McGivery](http://mcgivery.com/hello-backend-your-second-ionic-framework-app/#comment-10073)) that I've inserted into a blank Ionic/Cordova app..

```
.factory('userService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getUsers: function () {
            return $http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10').then(function (response) {
                return response.data.results;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, the code is returning a 404 when debugging as an Android device and

```
APPHOST9623: The app couldn’t resolve ms-appx-web://com.ionicframework.ionicblankapp/www/{{item.user.picture.thumbnail}} because of this error: DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE.
```

when debugging in Windows emulator. I can visit the URL in any external browser and see the json results. If I Ctrl+click the URL in the VS editor, the internal browser show 'Navigation to the webpage was cancelled' and a File Download warning dialog appears asking if I wish to Open or Save the api.json result.

I added this CSP to index.html `<head>` in the hopes that my problem was with Cordova refusing the connection

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: http://api.openweathermap.org https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

and turned my firewall off. All to no avail. I found some related issues that seemed to concern updating web.config for IIS, but am unsure how that would relate to an Android debugger running in Chrome.

I'm new to both Cordova and Ionic, so forgive me if this is a real rookie problem.

Comment: Are you testing in Ripple simulator? This might explain the 404 (Ripple keeps complaining about the missing cordova.js but this error will disappear on real device). And what Windows simulator are you using? Also feel free to check out a simple [ionic demo project](https://github.com/swifmaneum/RandomUser) of mine, which also uses randomuser.me

Comment: I ignore the missing cordova.js. The 404 is returned on the $http.get above (to https://randomuser.me). I'll be checking your demo right now.